# Why a std::get_time() simple example fails parsing on WSL Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: c++, g++, std, wsl-2, gettime

I am trying to run a very simple example of the [`std::get_time()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) but the parse is failing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>
 
int main()
{
  std::tm                     t = {};
  std::istringstream          ss("04-02-2022 3:04:32");
  ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S");
  if (ss.fail()) {
    std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    if ((ss.rdstate() & std::istringstream::failbit) != 0)
      std::cerr << "Error failbit\n";
    if ((ss.rdstate() & std::istringstream::goodbit) != 0)
      std::cerr << "Error goodbit\n";
    if ((ss.rdstate() & std::istringstream::eofbit) != 0)
      std::cerr << "Error eofbit\n";
    if ((ss.rdstate() & std::istringstream::badbit) != 0)
      std::cerr << "Error badbit\n";
  }
  else {
    std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << '\n';
  }
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 in Windows via WSL, which has g++ 9.4 installed, and I am compiling with the terminal command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 date.cpp -o date
```

The error is `std::istringstream::failbit`

Any Ideas what is going on?

Comment: Did you read the note written in the "Example" of the page?

Comment: do you mean "note: choose clang to observe the output. libstdc++ does not correctly implement the %b specifier:"

Comment: @MikeCAT I am sorry. I trying to run a very similar example not using the %b flag and it keeps failing. I just edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/5vT15KGcf) the failure in gcc 9.4.  It works if you change `3` to `03` in the hour field.

Even though `%H` is not supposed to require a leading zero, this appears to be a gcc bug where it does. See [Bug 78714](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78714). Despite being about `%b`, [this comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78714#c2) in that ticket goes into detail about how it also affects `%H` and other placeholders, too.

The code works fine in gcc 12.1.
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1fqao8hGd)

Comment: that is correct.. i realized that later night and I just came in here to responde.. So  thanks for the help. I was very troublesom, because the documentation explicitly say about the not need for the leading zeros. Thank you vey much @Remy